# Vaadin: How can I prevent the AppWidgetset.gwt.xml from continuously changing and becoming problematic in Git?

Tags: git, vaadin

On our project, the *AppWidgetset.gwt.xml* file continues have the following lines added to it:

```
<inherits name="org.vaadin.patrik.GridFastNavigation" />
```

This line continues to repeat itself over and over. Ultimately, we end up having issues if we put it on ignore. Is there a remedy to this?

Comment: This sounds like it's automatically added so I'm guessing you're using maven or gradle? It's weird you're having duplicates, perhaps a bug in the maven/gradle plugin, but also this happens when you recompile your widgetset so why is it you're constantly recompiling it? It should be done only when adding/removing/upgrading add-ons or the Vaadin version. BTW what Vaadin versions are you using?

Comment: That is correct - we are using Maven. The Vaadin version is 7.6.8

Comment: Any chance you could share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) on github or similar and describe the steps to reproduce it? It's rather difficult to figure out just from this brief description